# Utility or method for joining MP4 files

Tags: file-formats, mac, windows, mp4

I have two MP4 files that I generated with [Camtasia Studio](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html). I need to join them together post rendering with Camtasia (it can't be done during the Camtasia rendering process). Looking for a utility or technique that will work to join these, preferably that doesn't require re-rendering all the video again.

**Update**: Either Windows (preferred) or Mac. Doesn't need a GUI if it is a good command-line app.

Comment: It would help to know what platform/OS you are using.

Comment: @filzilla: Either Windows (preferred) or Mac.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/q/51047/31983

Answer (score 4):

I think the simplest way to this is to use MP4Box.

```
./MP4Box -add file1.mp4 -cat file2.mp4 -cat file3.mp4 output.mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

I was encountering audio sync issues when trying to do this with Avidemux, but I came upon a two-step process that keeps the audio in sync:

1. Concatenate files using [MKVToolNix](https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/downloads.html) (I used version 7.4.0 for Mac). This results in a Matroska video (.mkv) file.
2. Remux the .mkv file to MP4 format using [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/download.html) (I used verison 2.6 for Mac). I chose the MP4v2muxer option in the Output Format section. This results in an MP4 file with audio and video in sync.

Answer (score 1):

[Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) should do the work.

1. Load File
2. Go to File -> Append and select File
3. To the left of the video window,

   - set video mode to Copy;
   - same for audio mode;
   - set format to MP4.
4. Go to File -> Save -> Video.

Comment: This does what I am looking for, but it is causing the audio to go out of sync at the join point. I am going to try and join and mix the audio from a separate channel.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using ffmpeg, and the `-vcopy` switch.  *Usually* this will work, but it depends on codec support.

Various builds of it have various codecs.  If one version of it doesn't work, try downloading a copy from a different site.

Answer (score 1):

i think [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/) can do this.  It's free on mac and pc.